# ExtTextOut fails with very long strings unless lower font quality specified

Tags: c++, mfc, draw

Sometimes our application needs to draw very long strings (e.g. 6,000 chars) using ExtTextOut. Sometimes ExtTextOut fails and returns zero and GetLastError returns zero as well.

To re-create the situation create a simple MFC Single Document application and then set the OnDraw to be:

```
void CTestExtTextView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
 CTestExtTextDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
 ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
 if (!pDoc)
  return;

 LOGFONT lfDetail = {0};
 lfDetail.lfHeight = -(::MulDiv(100, pDC->GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY), 720));
 lfDetail.lfCharSet = ANSI_CHARSET;
 lfDetail.lfOutPrecision = OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
 lfDetail.lfQuality = CLEARTYPE_QUALITY;
 lfDetail.lfWeight = 400;
 _tcscpy_s(lfDetail.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE, _T("Arial"));

 CFont font;
 font.CreateFontIndirectW( &lfDetail );

 CFont * pold = pDC->SelectObject( &font );

 CString str = L"2 <office:document-content xmlns:office=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0\" xmlns:style=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0\" xmlns:text=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0\" xmlns:table=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0\" xmlns:draw=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0\" xmlns:fo=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" xmlns:meta=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0\" xmlns:number=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0\" xmlns:presentation=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0\" xmlns:svg=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0\" xmlns:chart=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0\" xmlns:dr3d=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0\" xmlns:math=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\" xmlns:form=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0\" xmlns:script=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0\" xmlns:ooo=\"http://openoffice.org/2004/office\" xmlns:ooow=\"http://openoffice.org/2004/writer\" xmlns:oooc=\"http://openoffice.org/2004/calc\" xmlns:dom=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events\" xmlns:xforms=\"http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" office:version=\"1.1\"><office:scripts/><office:font-face-decls><style:font-face style:name=\"Arial\" svg:font-family=\"Arial\" style:font-family-generic=\"swiss\" style:font-pitch=\"variable\"/><style:font-face style:name=\"Arial Unicode MS\" svg:font-family=\"&apos;Arial Unicode MS&apos;\" style:font-family-generic=\"system\" style:font-pitch=\"variable\"/><style:font-face style:name=\"Tahoma\" svg:font-family=\"Tahoma\" style:font-family-generic=\"system\" style:font-pitch=\"variable\"/></office:font-face-decls><office:automatic-styles><style:style style:name=\"co1\" style:family=\"table-column\"><style:table-column-properties fo:break-before=\"auto\" style:column-width=\"6.659cm\"/></style:style><style:style style:name=\"co2\" style:family=\"table-column\"><style:table-column-properties fo:break-before=\"auto\" style:column-width=\"7.408cm\"/></style:style><style:style style:name=\"co3\" style:family=\"table-column\"><style:table-column-properties fo:break-before=\"auto\" style:column-width=\"7.02cm\"/></style:style><style:style style:name=\"co4\" style:family=\"table-column\"><style:table-column-properties fo:break-before=\"auto\" style:column-width=\"7.214cm\"/></style:style><style:style style:name=\"co5\" style:family=\"table-column\"><style:table-column-properties fo:break-before=\"auto\" style:column-width=\"2.267cm\"/></style:style><style:style style:name=\"ro1\" style:family=\"table-row\"><style:table-row-properties style:row-height=\"0.473cm\" fo:break-before=\"auto\" style:use-optimal-row-height=\"true\"/></style:style><style:style style:name=\"ro2\" style:family=\"table-row\"><style:table-row-properties style:row-height=\"0.453cm\" fo:break-before=\"auto\" style:use-optimal-row-height=\"true\"/></style:style><style:style style:name=\"ta1\" style:family=\"table\" style:master-page-name=\"Default\"><style:table-properties table:display=\"true\" style:writing-mode=\"lr-tb\"/></style:style><style:style style:name=\"T1\" style:family=\"text\"><style:text-properties style:text-position=\"super 58%\"/></style:style></office:automatic-styles><office:body><office:spreadsheet><table:table table:name=\"Sheet1\" table:style-name=\"ta1\" table:print=\"false\"><office:forms form:automatic-focus=\"false\" form:apply-design-mode=\"false\"/><table:table-column table:style-name=\"co1\" table:default-cell-style-name=\"Default\"/><table:table-column table:style-name=\"co2\" table:default-cell-style-name=\"Default\"/><table:table-column table:style-name=\"co3\" table:default-cell-style-name=\"Default\"/><table:table-column table:style-name=\"co4\" table:default-cell-style-name=\"Default\"/><table:table-row table:style-name=\"ro1\"><table:table-cell office:value-type=\"string\"><text:p>Sample text for ExtTextOut</text:p></table:table-cell><table:table-cell office:value-type=\"string\"><text:p>Second Column Sample Text</text:p></table:table-cell><table:table-cell office:value-type=\"string\"><text:p>3<text:span text:style-name=\"T1\">rd</text:span> Column</text:p></table:table-cell><table:table-cell office:value-type=\"string\"><text:p>A More Lengthly bit of text just to make sure we increase the size of the line to something that might make ExtTextOut fail. It doesn&apos;t actually fail if we switch to Anti-Aliased Fonts. Not sure why. It also doesn&apos;t fail if we make the text shorter.</text:p></table:table-cell></table:table-row><table:table-row table:style-name=\"ro1\"><table:table-cell office:value-type=\"string\"><text:p>Sample text for ExtTextOut</text:p></table:table-cell><table:table-cell office:value-type=\"string\"><text:p>Second Column Sample Text</text:p></table:table-cell><table:table-cell office:value-type=\"string\"><text:p>3<text:span text:style-name=\"T1\">rd</text:span> Column</text:p></table:table-cell><table:table-cell office:value-type=\"string\"><text:p>A More Lengthly bit of text just to make sure we increase the size of the line to something that might make ExtTextOut fail. It doesn&apos;t actually fail if we switch to Anti-Aliased Fonts. Not sure why. It also doesn&apos;t fail if we make the text shorter.</text:p></table:table-cell></table:table-row><table:table-row table:style-name=\"ro1\"><table:table-cell office:value-type=\"string\"><text:p>Sample text for ExtTextOut</text:p></table:table-cell><table:table-cell office:value-type=\"string\"><text:p>Second Column Sample Text</text:p></table:table-cell><table:table-cell office:value-type=\"string\">";
 pDC->ExtTextOutW( 0,0, NULL, NULL, str, NULL );
 pDC->ExtTextOutW( 0,50, NULL, NULL, CString(L"But this will print out"), NULL );

 pDC->SelectObject( pold );
}
```

When you run the application you should see a single line 'But this will print out' half-way down the screen. If you set lfQuality = ANTIALIASED_QUALITY then it does actually print something out but just doesn't look right.

I've tested this on Vista and XP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further experimentation revealed that it doesn't appear to be specifically down to the length of the line or the resulting width, i.e. some lines with more characters and wider width would print just fine (e.g. a line with 7,365 chars and 40,360 width printed fine whereas a different line with 6,572 chars and 36,113 width failed). However, those same longer lines could be made to fail by changing something like the background colour of the line.

Which leads me to believe that this might be due to the complexity of the text line rather than just the length of the line and there is possibly an internal time-out, ie if ExtTextOut sees that it is taking too long then it just quits without printing any output.

Our solution was to chop up each line into 500 character chunks. So instead of a single ExtTextOut for a 6,000 chars line there are 12 ExtTextOuts each printing at the end of the last. This seems to work perfectly with very little performance hit and allows us to print very large lines (I stopped testing after 60,000 chars).

Answer (score 5):

I created a simple font:

```
CFont font;
font.CreatePointFont(720, _T("Times New Roman"));
CFont * pold = pDC->SelectObject( &font );
```

Then initialized a string until it failed to print. 761 characters worked, 762 failed:

```
CString str('a', 761); // Works
CString str('a', 762); // Fails
```

I tried a different font, it failed at a higher number of characters. Didn't make sense until I took the size of each string:

```
CSize s = pDC->GetTextExtent(str);
```

The width of both strings was ~32700; right near the 16-bit signed limit of 32767.

I was under the impression the 16-bit co-ordinate limitation was bumped to 32-bits starting with NT, so I have no clue why this wouldn't work on XP or Vista. I can vaguely remember a KB article on the subject, but I can't find it.

I tried using TextOut and DrawText and got the same results.

I then tried drawing a couple of lines to ensure they worked beyond the 16-bit limit:

```
pDC->MoveTo(10,0);
pDC->LineTo(10,38000);
pDC->MoveTo(10,38000);
pDC->LineTo(100, 38000);
```

and it worked fine, so my guess is there's a bug in the text based GDI functions.

Answer (score 1):

1. I observe the same problem with 4000 characters on Windows 10 (so this quite old question is still a topic in the year 2016)
2. I observe the problem on Windows 7 but only on one computer while it works on another computer with Windows 7.
3. When ExtTextOut fails it returns FALSE. So this seems not to be a bug, because the function already has noticed that something went wrong.

From these observations and from what the others wrote here I can deduce:

1. The conclusion from Fat Elvis that there is a 16 bit limit in the funcion is surely wrong, otherwise it would fail on ALL Windows 7 machines.
2. The theory of snowdude that a timeout plays a role make much sense because I observe the problem on the slow Windows 7 machine, while on a faster Windows 7 machine it draws the same string correctly. Probabaly the graphics driver has a time limit in which it must draw the characters. Additionally the MSDN says that the string should not be longer than 8192 characters. So Microsoft already states that there may be problems with too long strings.

The solution is surely not to use another font as suggested in the question. (The lower quality font makes drawing faster which again approves the theory of a timeout.)

I wrote a code that finally solves the problem.  The funcion is highly speed optimized.

```
// ATTENTION:
// The function returns FALSE on error but you cannot use GetLastError()!
BOOL ExtTextOutChunks(HDC h_Dc, int X, int Y, UINT u32_Flags, const RECT* pk_Rect, 
                      const WCHAR* u16_String, UINT u32_StrLen, const int* ps32_DX)
{
    // The maximum amount of characters that are printed at once.
    // The slower the computer the lower the value must be.
    const UINT CHUNK_SIZE = 500;

    // Speed optimization
    if (u32_StrLen <= CHUNK_SIZE)
        return ExtTextOut(h_Dc, X, Y, u32_Flags, pk_Rect, u16_String, u32_StrLen, ps32_DX);

    BOOL b_Return = TRUE;
    UINT u32_TxtAlign = GetTextAlign(h_Dc);
    BOOL b_SetFlag    = (u32_TxtAlign & TA_UPDATECP) == 0;

    // Set TA_UPDATECP to move the drawing position automagically after each drawing.
    // This is much faster than calling GetTextExtentPoint32() each time.
    if (b_SetFlag)
    {
        SetTextAlign(h_Dc, u32_TxtAlign | TA_UPDATECP);
        MoveToEx(h_Dc, X, Y, NULL);
    }

    while (u32_StrLen > 0)
    {
        UINT u32_Count = min(u32_StrLen, CHUNK_SIZE);

        if (!ExtTextOut(h_Dc, 0, 0, u32_Flags, pk_Rect, u16_String, u32_Count, ps32_DX))
        {
            b_Return = FALSE;
            break;
        }

        u32_StrLen -= u32_Count;
        u16_String += u32_Count;

        if (ps32_DX) ps32_DX += u32_Count;
    }

    // Reset the flag if it was not set before (ALWAYS!)
    if (b_SetFlag)
        SetTextAlign(h_Dc, u32_TxtAlign);

    assert(b_Return);
    return b_Return;
}
```